# loading the images one after other in specified timestamp in ios

Tags: ios

I am trying to place a banner on the top of the screen and I load different images in the banner on particular timestamp [ex:20sec].

First it has to load

```
[A] B C D E ,
A [B] C D E,
A B [C] D E,
A B C [D] E,
A B C D [E],
[A] B C D E,
```

automatically I am trying it from last 2 days.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Code:

```
    NSArray *imagesArray =   [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgA.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgB.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgC.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgD.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgE.png"] , nil];
    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    imageView.animationImages = imagesArray;
    imageView.animationDuration = 20*[imagesArray count]; // 20 is for the timestamp
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = -1;  // -1 for making the loop for ever, or you can use HUGE_VALF
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView startAnimating];
```

**Update**

To make the sliding animation use this one:

```
 NSArray *imagesArray;
 int photoCount;
 UIImageView *imageView;
-(void)setupImageView{
     photoCount = 0;
     [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgA.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgB.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgC.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgD.png"] ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgE.png"] , nil];         imageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
     imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:photoCount];
     [self.view addSubview:imageView];
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionPhotos) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 }

 -(void)transitionPhotos{


if (photoCount < [imagesArray count] - 1){
    photoCount ++;
}else{
    photoCount = 0;
}
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView1
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{ imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:photoCount]; }
                completion:NULL];    
}
```

Comment: this code will make images to slide ??

Comment: What you mean by "Slide" ??

Comment: sliding the images one after other [ex:slides in slideshow ppt]

Comment: No it won't, it just change the image of the banner every 20 second as you asked for !!

Comment: can u help me how to change that to slide show

Comment: it will slide horizontally or vertically ???